# pyspark print in for loop not working properly and skips some values

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, bigdata

I wrote a pyspark code like this:

```
for current_date in dates_list:
    print(f'loop started: {current_date}')
    loop_start_date = current_date - timedelta(days=90)
    dates_ = [loop_start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((current_date - loop_start_date).days + 1)]
    dates = ','.join(map(lambda date: date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), dates_))
    
    res= spark.read.parquet(f'my_path/day={{{dates}}}')
    
    print(f'loop continued: {current_date}')
    print('----------')
```

in the out put I expect get **same values** in first and second print as I do not change `current_date`. output is like this:

```
loop started: 2023-01-01
loop continued: 2023-01-01
----------
loop started: 2023-01-02
loop continued: 2023-01-03
----------
loop started: 2023-01-04
loop continued: 2023-01-04
----------
```

in the next run, it does not necessarily happen next time on the same date. also loop start and loop continue may have more than 1 day of difference.
why it is happening? how to solve it?

Comment: Based on what I can see, this is less likely to be a pyspark problem, and more likely to be a python code problem. The date objects inside your `dates_list` are being unexpectedly changed. For example, are you reusing your variable names like `loop_start_date` when generating `dates_list`?

Comment: No. dates_list is set with other variables. but I don't think the variable changes because of the code. I didn't assign anything to the current_date and dates_list variables except in the definition. 
note that if there was a problem with the code, it should be reproduced on the same date every time but it does not happen like this. for example the next time I ran this code. 2023-01-02 was okay and the problem occurred on another date.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The way your question is defined right now, we as reviewers cannot reproduce the behaviour you're describing so it's just a guessing game.